# New to Aptana, two questions on deployment

Tags: eclipse, aptana, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I've moved to Aptana from DW (mainly to get better Phonegap/Android integration). I'm using Aptana integrated into Eclipse (i.e. installed Eclipse and then added Aptana).
I have two questions.

1. How can I configure Aptana/Eclipse to copy files to my local development server when I want to test?  I can clearly do this in the filesystem outside the IDE, but would like it inside on a button or menu.
2. How can I configure the process to use, for example, the Google closure tools for js and css as part of my build/deployment process?  I'd like to automatically minify the js and/or be able to use the css extensions offered (variables).

I get the feeling that all this should be possible since Eclipse is so configurable, but I don't know where to start.  Would Ant do this for me?  How?

Would appreciate some pointers.

Thanks

Abo

Answer (score 2):

I can answer your first question.

If you have the Aptana plug-in installed, you will have an option on your right-click menu titled "Deploy". Expanding the deploy setting will reveal the option to "Run Web Deployment Wizard...". From here, if you are using a web server as mentioned, you will probably want to choose the FTP/SFTP/FTPS option. Fill in the form with your servers information and be sure to run a test to make sure things are working properly.

I always check the "Automatically sync my changes with the remote site" box and then select the "Automatically sync in both directions" radio button. This will automatically deploy my current file to my web-server upon a save.

You may also want to only select the "Automatically sync from my machine to remote site", the reason I choose both ways is because I sometimes work from different machines and it helps me keep things in sync. A little tweaking and it should save you a lot of time and effort!

[Using Indigo Release 1, and Aptana Studio 3]

Answer (score 0):

Aptana don't include support for "Google Closure", you can instead use "Eclipse" or "WebStorm".

I hope below links will help -

http://www.daveoncode.com/2009/11/23/automatically-compile-javascript-applications-using-google-closure-and-ant/

and this stack exchange thread -
[Google closure compiler usage WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710109/google-closure-compiler-usage-webstorm)