# Google closure compiler usage WebStorm

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, google-closure-compiler, webstorm

I like to use the [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) in [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). I've downloaded it over npm.

```
npm install closure
```

Never really used node and i don't know how to execute the commandline. Please do not blame me. Knowledge don't came from nowhere and this question is programming related.

[image]

Comment: On _WebStorm 2018.1_, to find this form, go to `Preferences > Tools > File Watcher`, then click on the `+` icon to `Add`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put the path to the Closure compiler .jar there, the default arguments which phpstorm gives you are fine.

I did not install closure compiler via node.js, but I did it with coffeescript and it should be somewhere in the npm folder.

Comment: I did it the same way before I used Node!

Comment: don't get any .jar file by installing it over node, its working right now by downloading the jar file separate

Comment: Guys, may be I missed something, but it seems that it will not analyze Closure dependencies, I mean provide/require stuff. In such a case this feature is almost useless.